# Amadeus SOAP webservice Air_Multiavailability : How to pass more than one city in source and destination locations?

Tags: search, amadeus

We have flights operating from NYC and EWR and need to include both the flight result sets from say DFW to NYC & EWR in single Air_Multiavailability (using v13) SOAP webservice request.  Please help.

How to pass more than 1 city in source or destination while searching for point to point flights (kind of including near by cities/airports) or say find flights based on radius with in 50 miles or 100 miles.
Current api attributes where single source city can be passed : Air_MultiAvailabilityRequestSection.availabilityProductInfo.departureLocationInfo

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: For Enterprise related questions please get in touch with your account manager.